# Задержка отправки запроса при парсинге

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Хочу реализовать задержку между запросами, примерно понимаю, что для этого нужно использовать schedule. Но как это реализовать в своём коде - не понимаю.

```
for i in range(30, 60):
    url = f'https://www.livelib.ru/reviews~{i}'
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    books_links = soup.find_all(class_ = 'lenta-card-book__link')
    for books_link in books_links:
        server = 'https://www.livelib.ru'
        book_pages_href = server + books_link.get('href')
        book_pages.append(book_pages_href)

with open('book_pages.txt', 'a') as file:
    for L in book_pages:
        file.write(f'{L}\n')

with open('book_pages.txt') as file:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

    book_title = []


    for line in lines:
        q = requests.get(line)
        result = q.content

        soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'lxml')
        book_title = [soup.find('h1').text]
        print(book_title)
```

Запрос выглядит примерно так. И подобных ему запросов еще около 5.
При сборе данных в какой-то момент, вместо нужного текста я получаю - "Подождите несколько секунд идёт переадресация на страницу".

Можно ли реализовать задержку на отправку запроса при каждой итерации? Или как-то по-другому решить проблему?

Comment: Понимаю, что проблема может быть связана и просто с нестабильным соединением, но всё же

Comment: 1 задержка по времени между запросами (модуль time time.sleep(2)) 2 Задержка по времени через определенное количество запросов 3 Сахранить не удачные попытки запросов и повторить запрос (не удачные попытки)

Comment: @СергейШ, попробовал сделать, как вы посоветовали. У меня, все равно, после 45+- запроса, перестают сохраняться данные, только сообщения о переадресации.

Comment: у меня ваш код с первого запроса на рекапчу(защита от ботов) кидает.

Comment: @СергейШ , у меня такого не происходило.  но все равно код работает не очень долго, хотя он не вылетает с ошибкой. Не очень понимаю, как это избежать. Я раз в какое-то время меняю впн-сервер. Может, вы знаете, проблема в том, как я написал код или в том, что у сайта хорошая защита?

Comment: Сайт за Cloudflare, а потому у вас просто так обойти это не получиться. Даже если вы потом будете делать повторно запросы. Тут, скорее всего, можно использовать прокси. Вот только, думаю, что бесплатные не подойдут. Ну, или, можно парсить selenium. Хотя, точно не скажу. Возможно, что и там будет запрос капчи. Нужно проверять.

Comment: @Евгений спасибо! Попробую с селениумом это сделать

Comment: Косим под браузер (модуль fake_useragent), создаем сессию, обновляем headers {закос под браузер, а точнее 'User-Agent') заходим на 'livelib.ru' (чтоб получить куки, которые сохраняться в сессий), парсим по сценарию. Если нас раскрыли ("Подождите несколько секунд идёт переадресация на страницу") есть два варианта развития событий 1 использовать прокси (можно использовать публичные, предварительно просеить) 2 С помоцью браузера (Selenium или Pyppeteer) заходим на 'livelib.ru/service/ratelimitcaptcha' ждем когда нас перекинет на 'livelib.ru'

Comment: и можно парсить далее,  но лучше вытащить из браузера headers и cookies и обновить сессию в коде.

Comment: Вариант с куками и заголовком я пробовал. Создал для них сессию. Единственное. что не менял агента на лету. Тем не менее, сессия не помогла, равно как заголовки и куки. К сожалению. А вот селениум, особенно в стелс-режиме, вполне себе справляется. Специально поюзал немного. Страниц сорок прощелкал )) Если просто для реквеста, тут могут прокси помочь, это да. Вот только не всякие подойдут. Но парсить лайвлиб платными прокси - то еще удовольствие ))

Comment: У селенимума есть один не достаток и это скорость выполнения кода.

Comment: @Евгений  Пробую как раз перенести код на селениум. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @СергейШ Да, заметил. Спасибо.

Comment: @Евгений Основная проблема у меня начиналась, когда начинал парсить заголовки. А ссылки на книги без проблем собирались.